# Terraform: Making a list from part of another list

Tags: amazon-web-services, interpolation, terraform

I have a requirement to make a simple list of names from this items list.
I've tried splitting and jointing various bits together but to no avail.
Does anyone know if this is possible with Terraform without the use of the null resource?

```
items = [
#"name;      instance_port;             listener_port;          tag;"
"name1;     60014;                   443;                   Some text",
"name1;     60012;                   443;                   Some text"
]
```

Result should be a string of names

```
"name1,name2"
```

Comment: I can't think of a good way to do that off the top of my head but you can probably do something better if you have more control of the data structure to make it into a map or at least coerce the input. What is your wider goal here? Where does that data come from and how are you intending to use it?

Comment: I did think of using a map but a map always ends up being processed as a list sorted by the key names. So if you add another item to the map they could all get re-shuffled making reading the Terraform plan a nightmare.

Comment: So what's the wider problem?

Comment: It's bit difficult to explain but we have to create AWS ELBs using Terraform and then they get added to a vendor supplied CloudFormation stack, also using Terraform. We started with having the ELB names in a list, Tags in a list, etc, but the lists are getting to long to manage. We wanted to try and create a list like the one shown above. It is working fine for most purposes until we get to the situation where we need a simple list of names. I can do it with a null resource but wanted to find out if it could be done using basic interpolation.